# Shoulda - Passing parameters to controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shoulda

I've recently run into interesting problem passing parameters to my controller action from my functional test. Previously, I was passing the 'type' parameter (which is required by STI) like that and it worked:

```
setup do
  get :new, :type => "TimeOfUseTariff"
end
```

However things have changed and i now need to pass something[type].  I've tried the following but nothing seems to work:

```
setup do
  get :new, "something[type]" => "TimeOfUseTariff"
end
```

Neither:

```
setup do
  get :new, "something[type]".constantize => "TimeOfUseTariff"
end
```

Is there any way how I can achieve passing this extra parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if the controller expects "something[type]":

```
setup do
  get :new, :something => {:type => "TimeOfUseTariff"}
end
```